# Drupal : How to filter views result to the current language nodes else default language

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, internationalization, translation, drupal-views

I'm using a view to show a list of nodes and would like to return only current language related nodes or if the node do not exist in this language. I would like return instead the node with the default language.

Currently I'm using `filter - Content : language = Current user's language`.

But I can't return the node with the default language if the condition is `false`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, for some reason the views setting `Field Language: Current user's language` does not work and I have to add the `current user's language` filter to every view on one of my D7 instances. Have you figured it out yet?